# javascript spell checking

Tags: javascript, spell-checking

I need a quick solution of javascript spell checking. Although all the browsers underlines misspelled words.I need the same but manual by myself. Actually my application is also running on mac, and spell check is not working there.

Please help me in this regards ASAP.

Comment: `ASAP` and no attempts posted don't really compel people to help you. Please post at least what you've done and looked for

Comment: I need the solution for mac systems, where default javascript spell checking (underline with red curved line) is not working. Also I want to do some action if spell are not proper, just for simplicity, wanna raise some event when some thing is misspelled, like javascript alert.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this  [jquery-spellchecker](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-spellchecker/)

here is a [sample](http://spellchecker.jquery.badsyntax.co.uk/example.html)

Comment: i didn't see him mention jQuery...

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library. he want's to use javascript and hasn't said he won't use libraries - so mentioning jquery + spellchecker-plugin seems to be legit.

Comment: Thanks for your demo example, it works for me...

Comment: try http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com  not jquery dependent. commercial